# find PDF of different continious random variable

Tags: probability

I am clueless with solving such problems.

Suppose i have some PDF :

${p_z(x)=1/(x^2+1)}$

and i need to find PDF of different continious random variable i.e z=${1/y}$

My attempt:

1. Found CDF for the initial random variable
2. Replaced it with new continious variable (1/y)
3. Took the derivative of the resulting function

My solution is incorrect. I don't get why

Comment: What are the bounds for your pdf? Is it integrating to $1$?

Comment: @PC1 Nothing is said about bounds in the task. Assume that the integral converges and is equal to one

Comment: The integral, when evaluated over $\mathbb{R}$, is equal to $\pi$.

Comment: @FabrizzioMuzz never heard of it. I would like to read more about this integral, however it does not help to solve this problem.

Comment: @RamilAhmedov it is the derivative of $\tan^{-1}(x)$ and is perhaps one of the first things taught in high school calculus .

Comment: @RamilAhmedov Google on Cauchy distribution. Then you can check whether you made an error. As commented the original function is not a PDF. For gaining that it must be divided by $\pi$.

Comment: @drhab i didn't want to place whole equation, because i just wanted to understand the algorithm for solving such problems. In this case $p_z(x) = 1/pi * 1/(1+x^2)$. Conditions are the same

Comment: @RamilAhmedov Ah I see....then you can try and google Jacobian transformation for Random variables. Wait , I'll post an answer explaining

Comment: The algorithm fails on 2) because the rv $X$ can take negative values.

Comment: @drhab . Not to mention that the transformation is not defined when $X$ takes the value $0$. That is $x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}$ is not a well defined function on $\Bbb{R}$ let alone Borel Measurable .